# Are Ansible date time functions having problem with microseconds?

Tags: ansible

I have input strings with dates in, I guess, iso8601_micro format with UTC offset.

```
2021-12-01 16:05:38.051000+03:00
```

I want to convert them to date time. (So I could compare it with interval provided by user)
But Ansible stumbles after dot on microtime.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ ('2021-12-01 16:05:38.051000+03:00')| to_datetime }}"
```

and yields "unconverted data remains" error:

```json
{
"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({u'msg': [u\"{{ ('2021-12-01 16:05:38.051000+03:00')| to_datetime }}\"]}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: unconverted data remains: .051000+03:00\n\n
}
```

I've tried to pass it's format to datetime filter

```yaml
- debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ ('2021-12-01 16:05:38.051000+03:00')| to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z') }}"
```

But I'm getting exactly the same output.

I've tried the inverse way.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'|strftime }}"
```

This time %f format directive was just ignored:

```json
{
    "msg": [
        "2021-12-16 00:29:18.%f+0000"
    ]
}
```

But %f directive should be valid I at least, according to
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html
and
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

So is this the bug?
Or it's just me?

Comment: Mind that `%z` expects `+0300` and not `+03:00`.

Comment: For me doing: `- debug: msg="{{ '2021-12-15 21:45:06.264965+0300'| to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z') }}"` works as expected.

Comment: What are your version of Python and Ansible? `ansible --version`

Comment: Hi, thanks for response.
I have ansible 2.9.27, however I'm using python 2.7.5 for legacy projects compatibility. This can be the case, will retry in more modern python environment.

Which directive should be used to parse +03:00 offsets?

Comment: So yes, the reason was indeed fourth colon in UTC offset, which doesn't fit %z offset directive, just the error message was a bit misleading. 
Yet I wonder why even ansible itself outputs the result of to_dattetime conversion as:
```"msg": [ "2021-12-01 16:05:38.051000+03:00" ]``` that is with colon in UTC offset.
By the way my example string(with colon as well) I've received from one of ansible modules.

Anyway, it works with python 3, when 4th colon has been removed, and ansible with python 2.7.* thinks z is 'a bad directive'.

Answer (score 0):

About `%f` being ignored with the `strftime` filter I have the same issue.

By chance I found the workaround of using the `now()` function in my case:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |
      time: {{ now(utc=True, fmt="%Y %f") }}
      time: {{ "%Y %f" | strftime }}
      time: {{ "%Y %f" | strftime(utc=True) }}
```

which outputs:

```
ok: [host] =>
  msg: |-
    time: 2023 873102
    time: 2023 %f
    time: 2023 %f
```

---

**Edit:** Actually it seems normal to me, the `strftime` filter uses `time.gmtime` ([source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/ac3ae94ae1451132417a30078d5b0e95c6df4da3/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L98-L99)).
The [`time.gmtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.gmtime) function returns a [`struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) which works at the second precision.

---

**Edit2:** For fun, it's actually easy to make a custom filter that works as expected:

```py
# filter_plugins/strftime2.py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'strftime2': self.strftime2,
        }

    def strftime2(self, string_format, utc=False):
        ts = datetime.now(timezone.utc if utc else None)
        return ts.strftime(string_format)
```

with this task:

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          my_filter: "{{ '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z' | strftime2(utc=true) }}"
```

gives the following output:

```
ok: [host] =>
  msg: |-
    my_filter: "2023-11-03T12:51:43.959484+0000"
```